# jumpy css font-size transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

**Problem:**

- Hover cursor over the X and wait until the div is fully collapsed.
- Move away from the X
- Observe how div jumps to the bottom and straight back up.

**Question:**

How can I make the div expand without the font wrapping during the animation. ( I'm using a delayed font-size now, which seems to be problematic ).

**Constrains:**

These constrains are in effect due to the broader design of this isolated snippet.

- Can not disable wrapping on `outer` div ( except for during the animation ).
- Can not add a fixed width **or height** to the `inner` div.
- Can not use JS

**More context:**

I'm using `white-space:nowrap` for the hover state so the text doesn't wrap while the div collapses. I then use a delayed `font-size` transition to prevent the text from wrapping while the div expands again ( since it's not possible to animate `white-space` or `display` ).
It seems like somehow the `font-size` of 0 get's lost for a fraction of a second at the beginning of the animation or something. Not sure exactly why it's jumping in the beginning.

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.button {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.outer:hover {
  width: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.outer .inner {
  font-size: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: font-size 0s 2s;
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="button">
X
</div>
<div class="inner"> 
This is the variable content of the box
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.button {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
}
.outer:hover {
  width: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.outer .inner p {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.outer:hover .inner p {
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="button">
    X
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <p>This is the variable content of the box</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

target the p, change the transition to all.

Comment: Sorry this answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer well if you tried it it works, test it on codepen.io compare the differences compared to your code. i have changed the transition to all aspects and not just the font size, i also made the inner container a paragraph instead of just plain text.

Comment: No need to use codepen if you can use SO's snippets. I edited your post to feature one, however I'm not sure what I'm seeing is what you intended...

Comment: @Unifx I have tested it, the whole text jumps now when expanding. That is possibly worse then the current solution.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer i fixed by adding another transition to the inner on expand... works perfect

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer and author: I don't know what you guys are seeing, but you might want to have a look at this in Firefox. It's still jumpy, and always will be without a parent container

Comment: @TheThirdMan This does seem to work properly in firefox for me. This solution really is least intrusive out of the proposed solutions. Thanks for your answer as well tough !!

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer: [This is how it looks for me](http://files.blueshack.net/images/jumpy-hover-demo.gif) in Firefox ESR 45.2.0 / Debian

Comment: @TheThirdMan I'm happy with it working on firefox 48 on OSX 10.11. I don't have linux users :D

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- add `line-height: 22px;` to `.outer .inner`; and
- add `height: 22px;` to `.outer`.

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.button {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.outer:hover {
  width: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.outer .inner {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: font-size 0s 2s;
}

.outer:hover .inner {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="button">
X
</div>
<div class="inner"> 
This is the variable content of the box
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the solution I was gonna go for but at least it shows me my current approach isn't gonna work at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems you get when you change an object's size on hovering over itself. The trick to solving this is to use a parent container to hover on, which will always cover the width of the element, causing a slight ghosting effect, but compared to the visual effects your original solution had, this is much cleaner.

Your list of constraints isn't easy to work with, and the only way I can see this being solved under these circumstances is by making `button` and element that doesn't interfere with the document flow inside your container, so that nothing will wrap. Here are a few different attempts, one of which hopefully suiting your requirements:

**solution fitting all contraints, using `white-space`**

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
}
.outer {
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.button:after {
  content: 'X';
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.outer-wrapper:hover .outer {
  width: 30px;
}
.outer .inner {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2em;
  transition: font-size 0s 2s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.outer-wrapper:hover .outer .inner {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      This is the variable content of the box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**solution fitting all contraints, changing the markup to use `pre`**

This solution introduces a `pre` element, which will prevent wrapping on it's own because it inherits a `white-space:pre` declaration from it's default style.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
}
.outer {
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: width 2s;
}
.button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.button:after {
  content: 'X';
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.outer-wrapper:hover .outer {
  width: 30px;
}
.outer .inner {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2em;
  transition: font-size 0s 2s;
}
.outer-wrapper:hover .outer .inner {
  font-size: 0px;
}
pre {
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      <pre>This is the variable content of the box</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**hacking your way out**

You need to prevent the inner div's contents from wrapping, and if you don't want to do this via `white-space`, the only option left is to replace all whitespaces in it with non-breaking spaces to make sure the element *can't* wrap anymore:

```
<div class="inner">
  This&nbsp;is&nbsp;the&nbsp;variable&nbsp;content&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;box
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually perfect !

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer: I just edited it to account for the set width on the inner div - but if you're already happy, all the better :)

Comment: Ah I was just typing that was a problem ! Please do update if you have a working solution for that !

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer: There isn't a working solution for that. You have to give the inner content a width or prevent it in another way from wrapping. That is what the white-space property does, but I added a solution with a `pre` element, if that works for you... but all in all, using `white-space` is really what you should go with.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer: Hm, I can't find the contraint of not using `white-space` in your list anymore... did I misread that? If using `white-space` is alright, this is easily solveable with your original markup.

Comment: I changed it to the broader "can not disable wrapping" which should include not using `white-space` property

Comment: Ah, pre is off course a way to "disable wrapping" :)
Either way, I disabled the collapse animation all together to resolve the issue for now. Thanks for your efforts tough !

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer: Your constraints state that you don't want "disable wrapping on `outer` div", which my solution fullfills. You even use it for your inner div yourself. There is also no reason why you *wouldn't* want to use it that I can see...